# Searching on associations in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, ransack

Spree reports utilize ransack for searching. According to the ransack documentation I should be able to use the following line of code to search for all the orders with line items containing more than one item.

```
Spree::Order.ransack(line_items_quantity_gt: 1)
```

But when I enter that line in the console I get the following output

```
Ransack::Search<class: Spree::Order, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>
```

According to the ransack documentation that should work. The association doesn't appear to be accepted in the search parameters. Line items is in the list provided by Spree::Order.ransackable_associations so I'm a little confused as to why this isn't working.

Comment: I am facing same issue right now, searching order by variants sku.

Comment: I figured out the issue and that might help to them facing the issue. The association which I was querying was not on the list `whitelisted_ransackable_associations` of the model. I added that and bingo, it worked.

Comment: This rings a bell as to how I ended up fixing this issue myself. Submit an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I was looking for a reason why associations are not worked in api, and even in code with rails console. Some how this topic not seen in google. I found it only by `whitelisted_ransackable_associations`. I show in answer how exactly to override defaults in app.

Answer (score 0):

Some associations (attributes, scopes) my be **whitelisted**, others are ignored by ransack.

To override defaults in app add (to) file `app/controllers/spree/products_controller_decorator.rb`:

```rb
Spree::ProductsController.class_eval do

  Spree::Product.whitelisted_ransackable_associations = %w[taxons stores variants_including_master master variants]

end
```